# openOCD GDB debugging issue using Eclipse, variables show phantasy values

Tags: eclipse, gdb, openocd, esp-idf

Hopefully some can help me to nail this down. I am using Eclipse IDE for ESP-IDF projects. Everything works as expected, however variables do not show their real values. I have tried many options like using various openOCD versions. I tried out ESP-IDF using VScode with exactly the same result. Everything works, just the variables shown are anything then to what they really set.

As this problem persists throughout  various IDE's, toolchain and openOCD versions I am wondering what that could be.

Anyone any idea what to do?

Comment: How do you know they are not showing the "real" values? What do you see? What did you expect to see?

Comment: First you need to convince yourself 100% that the value shown is not correct.  If you are sure it's not correct, then the most likely explanation is incorrect debug information.  When you compile, the compiler generates additional debug information that tells the debugger where the value of each variable can be found.  Sometimes the compiler can get this wrong, in which case the debugger will look in the wrong place for the variable.  This incorrect behaviour is often triggered when compiling with optimisation, but sometimes it might just be a compiler bug.

Comment: @greg all variables show greasy values and the program would not work at all if the sown values are right. I have this issue since ever and help me by logging the real values through the logging library

Comment: @Andrew compiler bug in ESP-IDF where all other people have no issue with this tool chain? I am compiling with debug level -Og however I see a compiler message that the free RTos symbols are not available and variables in arrays on the stack are <unavailable>